# Debugging An ATL Exe COM Server

Tags: c++, debugging, com, atl

In Visual Studio 6, I have written an ATL COM server EXE. I want to debug this and put a breakpoint at the start of the method I am calling. I start debug and then call the method from the other EXE but the breakpoint is never hit. This was working fine a couple of weeks ago. I could break into it no problem. I can't work out what has changed that this is no longer working. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your exe or pdb probably don't match the source. Try rebuilding the project, and make sure the executables you've just built are used by the server.

FWIW, you can also place a call to [DebugBreak](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679297%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in your code. If the source and executables indeed don't match, the debugger will let you know when it breaks.